# A recursive function to extract the files from a nested JSON like object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have a data which consists of directory name and its files . Given a specific directory name in the argument say , I need to find all the files it encloses . 
my data :

```
var fileData = {
      dir : 'app',
      files : [
        'index.html',
        {
          dir : 'js',
          files: [
            'main.js',
            'app.js',
            'misc.js',
            {
              dir : 'vendor',
              files : [
                'jquery.js',
                'underscore.js'
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          dir : 'css',
          files : [
            'reset.css',
            'main.css'
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

I have a function listfiles where I am passing the directory name

```
listFiles(fileData, 'js')
```

Expected output :

```
['main.js','app.js','misc.js','jquery.js','underscore.js']
```

In my code i am able to get the answer in the console but could not return the value .

```
listFiles = (data, dirName) => {
          var filesArray = [];
          matchedDir = (data,dirName) => {
            data['files'].map(el => {
                if(typeof(el) === 'object'){
                  return matchedDir(el,dirName)
                }
                else{filesArray.push(el)}
              })
              console.log(filesArray)
            }
          if(Object.values(data).includes(dirName)) {
            return matchedDir(data,dirName)
          }
          else{
            data['files'].map(el => {
              if(typeof(el) === 'object'){
                return this.listFiles(el,dirName)
              }
            })
          }
        return filesArray
}
```

Comment: What happens if more than one matching directory name is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the result array on the initial call of the function, and pass that array along on every recursive call:

```js
const getAllFilesFromDirectory = ({ dir, files }, dirToFind, result = [], parentMatch = false) => {
  const addItemsThisDirectory = parentMatch || dir === dirToFind;
  files.forEach((fileOrDir) => {
    if (typeof fileOrDir === 'string') {
      if (addItemsThisDirectory) {
        result.push(fileOrDir);
      }
    } else {
      getAllFilesFromDirectory(fileOrDir, dirToFind, result, addItemsThisDirectory);
    }
  });
  return result;
};

var fileData = {
  dir: 'app',
  files: [
    'index.html',
    {
      dir: 'js',
      files: [
        'main.js',
        'app.js',
        'misc.js',
        {
          dir: 'vendor',
          files: [
            'jquery.js',
            'underscore.js'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      dir: 'css',
      files: [
        'reset.css',
        'main.css'
      ]
    }
  ]
};
console.log(getAllFilesFromDirectory(fileData, 'js'));
```

Comment: I think the second parameter is directory name and not file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decomposed approach to the problem using functional techniques.

First implement a generic `files` function -

```
const emptyTree = 
  { dir: "", files: [] }

const files = (tree = emptyTree, path = "") =>
  Object(tree) === tree
    ? tree.files.flatMap(f => files(f, `${path}/${tree.dir}`))
    : [ `${path}/${tree}` ]

files(fileData)
// [ "/app/index.html"
// , "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// , "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]
```

Then implement `search` as a higher-order function, like `Array.prototype.filter` -

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const search = (test = identity, tree = emptyTree) =>
  files(tree).filter(test)
```

Finally, we can use `search` in intuitive ways -

```
search(f => f.endsWith(".js"), fileData)
// [ "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// ]

search(f => f.startsWith("/app/css"), fileData)
// [ "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]
```

By separating a tough problem into isolated parts, each function is easier to write, test, and maintain. With an added advantage that `files` and `search` offer even more functionality than your original function and they can be reused more easily in other areas of your program. Hopefully this demonstrates how higher-order functions give you increased flexibility – and with less code too.

Run the complete program in your own browser by expanding the snippet below -

```js
const fileData = 
  { dir: 'app', files: [ 'index.html', { dir: 'js', files: [ 'main.js','app.js','misc.js', { dir: 'vendor', files: [ 'jquery.js','underscore.js' ] } ] }, { dir: 'css', files: [ 'reset.css','main.css' ] } ] }

const emptyTree = 
  { dir: "", files: [] }

const files = (tree = emptyTree, path = "") =>
  Object(tree) === tree
    ? tree.files.flatMap(f => files(f, `${path}/${tree.dir}`))
    : [ `${path}/${tree}` ]

console.log(files(fileData))
// [ "/app/index.html"
// , "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// , "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]

const identity = x =>
  x

const search = (test = identity, tree = emptyTree) =>
  files(tree).filter(test)


console.log(search(f => f.endsWith(".js"), fileData))
// [ "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// ]

console.log(search(f => f.startsWith("/app/css"), fileData))
// [ "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]
```

---

Another approach is to use generators. Notice the similarity between this program and the one above -

```
const files = function* (tree = emptyTree, path = "")
{ if (Object(tree) === tree)
    for (const f of tree.files)  
      yield* files(f, `${path}/${tree.dir}`)
  else
    yield `${path}/${tree}`
}

const search = function* (test = identity, tree = emptyTree)
{ for (const f of files(tree))
    if (test(f))
      yield f
}
```

Now `files` and `search` return a lazy result, where results can be processed one-by-one as they come out of the generator. Or we can collect all of the results using `Array.from`. The results are the same -

```
Array.from(search(f => f.endsWith(".js"), fileData))
// [ "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// ]

Array.from(search(f => f.startsWith("/app/css"), fileData))
// [ "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]
```

Because generators can pause and resume, this program has the added advantage that the computation can stop early. By contrast, the first program using `Array.prototype.flatMap` and `Array.prototype.filter` will always iterate through the entire `tree`.

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser

```js
const fileData = 
  { dir: 'app', files: [ 'index.html', { dir: 'js', files: [ 'main.js','app.js','misc.js', { dir: 'vendor', files: [ 'jquery.js','underscore.js' ] } ] }, { dir: 'css', files: [ 'reset.css','main.css' ] } ] }

const emptyTree = 
  { dir: "", files: [] }


const files = function* (tree = emptyTree, path = "")
{ if (Object(tree) === tree)
    for (const f of tree.files)  
      yield* files(f, `${path}/${tree.dir}`)
  else
    yield `${path}/${tree}`
}

console.log(Array.from(files(fileData)))
// [ "/app/index.html"
// , "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// , "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]

const identity = x =>
  x

const search = function* (test = identity, tree = emptyTree)
{ for (const f of files(tree))
    if (test(f))
      yield f
}

console.log(Array.from(search(f => f.endsWith(".js"), fileData)))
// [ "/app/js/main.js"
// , "/app/js/app.js"
// , "/app/js/misc.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/jquery.js"
// , "/app/js/vendor/underscore.js"
// ]

console.log(Array.from(search(f => f.startsWith("/app/css"), fileData)))
// [ "/app/css/reset.css"
// , "/app/css/main.css"
// ]
```